# How to use FILTERXML calc function?

Tags: xml, import, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm using LibreOffice 5.1.1.3 (x64) and I would like to make a live import of a remote XML file. The file URL is: http://www.comune.palermo.it/xmls/VIS_DATASET_AGENZIE.xml

I have written this formula, but calc import only the firs row.

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("http://www.comune.palermo.it/xmls/VIS_DATASET_AGENZIE.xml"),"/main/DATA_RECORD")
```

Is it normal? How to import all the rows of the XPath query output?

In gdrive sheet it works with:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.comune.palermo.it/xmls/VIS_DATASET_AGENZIE.xml","/main/DATA_RECORD")
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `FILTERXML` returns the first match that it finds.  Use the `[]` syntax to specify a different match.

To get one DATA_RECORD in each row, enter this in cell A1:

```
=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("http://www.comune.palermo.it/xmls/VIS_DATASET_AGENZIE.xml"),"/main/DATA_RECORD[" & ROW() & "]")
```

Then drag the formula down using the square in the lower-right corner of the cell.

To get the entire page, use the `WEBSERVICE` command without `FILTERXML`.

For more powerful XML parsing with LibreOffice, it will be necessary to write a macro.  There are several UNO services available, for example Section 5.38 of [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro Document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).  Or you can write the macro in Java or Python and use one of their XML parsing libraries.

Comment: Thank you, but in this way it's not a great tool. 
Moreover it does not split the result in cells, but all is in in one cell.

I think that for this kind of thing I continue to use Gdrive sheet :(

Answer (score 1):

Starting with LibreOffice 5.2.2 the `FILTERXML` function in LibreOffice works correctly in an array context allowing much easier access to XPath array results.

You can create such a formula by selecting e.g. `A1:A10` and insert your formula `=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("http://www.comune.palermo.it/xmls/VIS_DATASET_AGENZIE.xml"),"/main/DATA_RECORD")` in A1 and press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Each cell will now contain a different entry of the returned XPath array. The corresponding bug report can be found at [the LibreOffice bug tracker](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88257).

---

For other people looking for importing XML documents into LibreOffice Calc. There is currently another way through the `Data->XML Source` dialog that allows to select part of an XML document and import it. There is also some work partly done for LibreOffice 6.0 to allow importing external data and transforming it before applying to the document. This might replace many use cases for `WEBSERVICE` + `FILTERXML`.

Comment: Couldn't find info on ”some work partly done for LibreOffice 6.0 to allow importing external data and transforming it before applying to the document.” Would you kindly shed light on this? Was it implemented?